# BitConverter.ToInt64 OverflowException

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitconverter

I had error "OverflowException" at first step (i=0). What is wrong in this code?

```
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = { _
          0, 54, 101, 196, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, _
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 202, 154, _
         59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
        255, 255, 255, 255, 1, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, _
        255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 86, 85, 85, 85, 85, _
         85, 255, 255, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 0, _
          0, 100, 167, 179, 182, 224, 13, 0, 0, 156, _
         88, 76, 73, 31, 242}

    Dim UintList As New List(Of UInt64)  
    For i As Integer = 0 To byteArray.Count - 1 Step 8 
        UintList.Add(BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, i))
    Next
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `ArgumentException`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804265/how-does-bitconverter-toint64-handles-a-byte-arry-with-32-bytes-a-256-bit-hash

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file to let the compiler help you discover why this is wrong.  It is not BitConverter that throws this exception.  It is the conversion from a negative Int64 to UInt64 that is not valid.  Use BitConverter.ToUInt64() instead.  Or maybe you want List(Of Int64), intention is hard to guess.

Comment: Thanks Hans.. Yes now working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

1. You let `BitConverter` convert your bytes to `Int64` values, which you try to insert into a `UInt64` collection. This can cause **`OverflowException`**, because `UInt64` cannot represent negative values.

   You need to match up the type of what `BitConverter` produces with what your list stores, so do either of the following (both not both!):

   - Replace `BitConverter.ToInt64(…)` with `BitConverter.ToUInt64(…)`.
   - Declare `Dim UintList As New List(Of Int64)` instead of as `List(Of UInt64)`.
2. Your array has a length (75 bytes) that is not divisible by 8, which will cause a **`ArgumentException`** on the last loop iteration. `BitConverter.ToInt64` expects that there will be at least 8 bytes available from the specified starting offset `i`. However, once it gets to offset 72, there are only 4 bytes left, which is not enough to produce a `Int64`.

   Therefore, you need to check whether there are enough bytes left to convert:

   ```
   For i As Integer = 0 To byteArray.Count - 1 Step 8 
       If i + 8 <= byteArray.Length Then
           … ' enough bytes available to convert to a 64-bit integer
       Else
           … ' not enough bytes left to convert to a 64-bit integer
       End
   Next
   ```